# Try to load a created Map in MKMapView

Tags: ios, google-maps, mkmapview, mapkit

I am trying to load my Map which I created with a kml File in Google-Maps. [The Google Maps Link.](https://maps.google.de/maps/ms?msid=216922877238935477022.0004d406a819496582bb2&msa=0) I have to say it is only an example, but it is the same principle.

The easiest way is to load in a WebView, but that is ugly in my eyes.

Thank you for reading my Question!

Best regards CTS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To load a `KML` into a `MKMapView`:

1. [Add the necessary frameworks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaLibrarytoaTarget.html) (`MapKit.framework` and `CoreLocation.framework`) to your target;
2. Load and parse the KML;
3. Create your annotations on the basis of the KML; and
4. Set your map's `region` to encompass the annotations.

Thus, that might look like:

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

- (void)loadKml:(NSURL *)url
{
    // parse the kml

    Parser *parser = [[Parser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    parser.rowElementName = @"Placemark";
    parser.elementNames = @[@"name", @"Snippet", @"coordinates", @"description"];
    parser.attributeNames = nil;
    [parser parse];

    // add annotations for each of the entries

    for (NSDictionary *locationDetails in parser.items)
    {
        MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
        annotation.title = locationDetails[@"name"];
        annotation.subtitle = locationDetails[@"Snippet"];
        NSArray *coordinates = [locationDetails[@"coordinates"] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([coordinates[1] floatValue], [coordinates[0] floatValue]);
        [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
    }

    // update the map to focus on the region that encompasses all of your annotations

    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    if ([self.mapView.annotations count] > 1)
    {
        region = [self regionForAnnotations:self.mapView.annotations];
        region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(region.center, MKCoordinateSpanMake(region.span.latitudeDelta * 1.05, region.span.longitudeDelta * 1.05));  // expand the region by 5%
    }
    else
    {
        id<MKAnnotation> annotation = self.mapView.annotations[0];
        region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(annotation.coordinate, 100.0, 100.0);
    }
    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

My `Parser` class is just a `NSXMLParser` subclass that I've written that will create an array of `items` one per occurrence of `rowElementName`, and for each row, it will grab the elements listed in the `elementNames` array.

Parser.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Parser : NSXMLParser

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *rowElementName; // this is the element name that identifies a new row of data in the XML
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *attributeNames;  // this is the array of attributes we might want to retrieve for that element name
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *elementNames;    // this is the list of sub element names for which we're retrieving values

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *items;    // after parsing, this is the array of parsed items

@end
```

Parser.m:

```
#import "Parser.h"

@interface Parser () <NSXMLParserDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *item;     // while parsing, this is the item currently being parsed
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableString *elementValue; // this is the element within that item being parsed

@end

@implementation Parser

- (id)initWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    self = [super initWithContentsOfURL:url];

    if (self)
    {
        self.delegate = self;
    }

    return self;
}

- (id)initWithData:(NSData *)data
{
    self = [super initWithData:data];

    if (self)
    {
        self.delegate = self;
    }

    return self;
}

- (id)initWithStream:(NSInputStream *)stream
{
    self = [super initWithStream:stream];

    if (self)
    {
        self.delegate = self;
    }

    return self;
}

#pragma mark - NSXMLParserDelegate methods

- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
    self.items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    if (!self.rowElementName)
        NSLog(@"%s Warning: Failed to specify row identifier element name", __FUNCTION__);
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:self.rowElementName])
    {
        self.item  = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        for (NSString *attributeName in self.attributeNames)
        {
            id attributeValue = [attributeDict valueForKey:attributeName];
            if (attributeValue)
                [self.item setObject:attributeValue forKey:attributeName];
        }
    }
    else if ([self.elementNames containsObject:elementName])
    {
        self.elementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if (self.elementValue)
    {
        [self.elementValue appendString:string];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:self.rowElementName])
    {
        [self.items addObject:self.item];
        self.item = nil;
    }
    else if ([self.elementNames containsObject:elementName])
    {
        [self.item setValue:self.elementValue forKey:elementName];
        self.elementValue = nil;
    }
}

@end
```

Finally, the only other utility method that my `loadKml` uses is `regionForAnnotations`, which defines a region based upon a series of annotations. [Rob Mooney wrote a simple routine](https://gist.github.com/923301) to do that:

```
- (MKCoordinateRegion)regionForAnnotations:(NSArray *)annotations {

    CLLocationDegrees minLat = 90.0;
    CLLocationDegrees maxLat = -90.0;
    CLLocationDegrees minLon = 180.0;
    CLLocationDegrees maxLon = -180.0;

    for (id <MKAnnotation> annotation in annotations) {
        if (annotation.coordinate.latitude < minLat) {
            minLat = annotation.coordinate.latitude;
        }
        if (annotation.coordinate.longitude < minLon) {
            minLon = annotation.coordinate.longitude;
        }
        if (annotation.coordinate.latitude > maxLat) {
            maxLat = annotation.coordinate.latitude;
        }
        if (annotation.coordinate.longitude > maxLon) {
            maxLon = annotation.coordinate.longitude;
        }
    }

    MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(maxLat - minLat, maxLon - minLon);

    CLLocationCoordinate2D center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((maxLat - span.latitudeDelta / 2), maxLon - span.longitudeDelta / 2);

    return MKCoordinateRegionMake(center, span);
}
```

Comment: wow thank you! this is the most comprehensive answer I've ever received. I try it soon as I can.

CTS

Comment: little question: `KmlAnnotation *annotation = self.mapView.annotations[0];
        region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(annotation.coordinate, 100.0, 100.0);` result in errors: `undeclared identifier`. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: Sorry, replace that with "`id<MKAnnotation> annotation = ...`. In my app I actually used a custom annotation, and one of those references to that slipped through my attempts to edit the code for simplicity/brevity.