# How to add Action selector to the popup bubble on Annotation view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, annotations, mkmapview, mapkit

I have very new to MapKit Implementation

In my app one page is to be map View

in that I have displayed bulk amount of pins and their Annotation actions.

**I have added a Discloser button on the *`popup bubble`* and set action for these discloser buttons as shown bellow.**

***`i Want to Same action When tap on that gray bubble`***

```
//To add a discloser button to show route map
        UIButton *detailBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView=detailBtn;
        [detailBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(showRoute:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        DisplayMap *ann=(DisplayMap *)annotation;
        detailBtn.tag = ann.detailButtonTag;



//viewForAnnotation DELEGATE for annotions
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:
(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = nil;
    if(annotation != mapView.userLocation)
    {
        static NSString *defaultPinID = @"com.invasivecode.pin";
        pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
        if ( pinView == nil ) pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID] ;
        pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
        pinView.animatesDrop = YES;

        //To add a discloser button to show route map
        UIButton *detailBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView=detailBtn;
        [detailBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(showRoute:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        DisplayMap *ann=(DisplayMap *)annotation;
        detailBtn.tag = ann.detailButtonTag;
    }
    else
    {
        [mapView.userLocation setTitle:@"I am here"];
    }
    return pinView;
}
```

But i Want to Same action When tap on that gray bubble..

how to do it[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the following delegate method to get the tap on the bubble.

```
    -(void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapInfoWindowOfMarker:(id<GMSMarker>)marker 
   {
    DetailViewController *Detail = [[DetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@" DetailViewController" bundle:nil];    
    Detail.data=marker.userData;  // passing the data    
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:restDetail animated:YES];  
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods for that in [MKMapViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html) :

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
```

For more detail on how to use these methods, you can check the [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15297919/1603072) by Rob.

**Update :**

For that you can use [Custom Callout](http://blog.asynchrony.com/2010/09/building-custom-map-annotation-callouts-part-1/). You can create Custom Button with the "showRoute" methods and add as a Sub view to the Custom Callout Content View.

Comment: These method to tap on pin

But i need an action to tap on popup bubble

Comment: @user2492409 : Check **Update** in my Answer.