# how to set pin event on mapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, annotations, mapkit, marker

I'm using a mapView from MapKit.h.
I have a mapView with some pins and I want to launch a function when I click on a pin.
In android I used `onMarkerClickListener` method, and I don't know if I can do something like this with MapKit.h.
Anyone can help me??

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a delegate method

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
```

which will get called when you tap on the pin. for this you should set 
    pin.canShowCallout = YES

for more details follow below link
[MKMapView MKPointAnnotation tap event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292318/mkmapview-mkpointannotation-tap-event)

Answer (score 1):

Here is below links can helps to reach your requirement with sample code.

http://jonathanfield.me/mkmapview-adding-pins-map-showing-annotations/

http://rshankar.com/how-to-add-annotation-to-mapview-in-ios/