# Registering a touch event on an MKPointAnnotation

Tags: swift, mapkit

I want to set up a `MKPointAnnotation` so that when it is tapped I can call another function. Is there anyway to add a gesture recognizer or something like that?

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292318/mkmapview-mkpointannotation-tap-event

Answer (score 6):

Implement `mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView!,didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView!)` in `MKMapViewDelegate`