# Ios how to handle tap on multiple annotation on same latitude

Tags: ios, objective-c, annotations, mkmapview

I am getting multiple annotation on same latitude and longitude now what i want to do is how to recognize which annotation is tapped or how to handle all incoming annotation on same lat n long so that user may detect he tapped on which annotation

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: see this link may be helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292318/mkmapview-mkpointannotation-tap-event

Comment: assign tag value to each annotation when you have created. And when tapped, identify by tag value