# Go to next controller without using CallOutForAccessory MKMapview

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I have a map view in that I am showing annotations. On clicking any annotation the callout (bubble with info) will appear above the annotation.

What I want is to navigate to another class by clicking the callout without using `CallOutForAccessory` delegate method. I have added touch gesture in `didselect` but it still didn't work. I have looked through the Internet but didn't find any solution for the same. Most of the solutions compromise of `CallOutForAccessory`. Please share your ideas if anyone has done this before.

Comment: This link will helpful for you [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292318/mkmapview-mkpointannotation-tap-event]

Comment: I tried but it is not helpful