# MKViewAnnotation custom callout

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkannotationview, callout

I try create my own custom callout. This mean, I try create something new instead black system callout.

In MKAnnotationView documentation you can read: "To provide custom callout views, override the leftCalloutAccessoryView method and use it to return the views."

But this is maybe something else that I want. Can you please give me an advise, how can I reach my goal?

Thank you.

Deny

Comment: You need to be more specific on what you mean by "something new".

Comment: iPhone or iPad? You can use popover for the former, but for the latter you probably want one of the 3rd party popover controls. For iPad I've done [something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14619356/1271826) where I don't show the callout, but respond to selecting the annotation.

Comment: "Something new" means callout with different background color, with different height and different corner radius. I need this change make for iPhone app, so in this case I can't use popover control. Maybe is the new MKAnnotationView selecting behaviour the only way.