# is it possible to make like a popup image when mapview annotation clicked?

Tags: ios, image, mkmapview, mapkit, mkannotation

I have a question regarding mapview annotations in ios. 
Is it possible to make an image popup by clicking on the annotation pin?
If I use these?:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    NSLog( @"selected annotation view" );

    [pictureView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"clubs.png"]];
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{  
    NSLog( @"deselected annotation view" );

    [pictureView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"beer.png"]];
}
```

I have tried setting image, but the imageview doesnt display the image..?
thanks in advance

Comment: If for iPad, you can use `UIPopoverController`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14619356/1271826. If for iPhone, there isn't a native popover controller, so you'd have to use some third party popover control or do something manually yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at creating a custom callout view. There are a number of 3rd party implementations that you can use / look at for inspiration. Perhaps start with [this search of CocoaControls](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=callout).