# MKPointAnnotation show image in label

Tags: objective-c, mapkit, mkpointannotation, mapkitannotation

Can you help me with MKPointAnnotation? I would like to replace the annotation text with an image. For example, "1094_00_m.jpg" should display the image that corresponds with the filename rather than the filename. The image thumbnail will appear in the white area. It this possible?

[image: Position of image]

Comment: Just to be clear, you're trying to alter the callout bubble, not the annotation pin itself? Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/a/17772487/1271826 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/14619356/1271826.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supply a custom MKAnnotationView. Now simply override `setSelected:animated:` to show a custom view instead of the built-in callout. What goes in the custom view is completely up to you.