# MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance throws "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"

Tags: ios, ios6, mkmapview, mapkit

i got a new issue and i don't know why... My further solution was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562669/try-to-load-a-created-map-in-mkmapview/14564399?noredirect=1#comment20570969_14564399) posted by Rob. I love his work and it works very well until the update comes to iOS 6.1.

```
- (void)loadKml:(NSURL *)url
{
    // parse the kml

    Parser *parser = [[Parser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    parser.rowElementName = @"Placemark";
    parser.elementNames = @[@"name", @"Snippet", @"coordinates", @"description"];
    parser.attributeNames = @[@"img src="];
    [parser parse];

    // add annotations for each of the entries

    for (NSDictionary *locationDetails in parser.items)
    {
        MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
        annotation.title = locationDetails[@"name"];
        annotation.subtitle = locationDetails[@"Snippet"];
        NSArray *coordinates = [locationDetails[@"coordinates"] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([coordinates[1] floatValue], [coordinates[0] floatValue]);
        [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
    }

    // update the map to focus on the region that encompasses all of your annotations

    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    if ([self.mapView.annotations count] > 1)
    {
        region = [self regionForAnnotations:self.mapView.annotations];
        region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(region.center, MKCoordinateSpanMake(region.span.latitudeDelta * 1.05, region.span.longitudeDelta * 1.05));  // expand the region by 5%
    }
    else
    {
        id<MKAnnotation> annotation = self.mapView.annotations[0];
        region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(annotation.coordinate, 100.0, 100.0); // >>>this line throws: "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"<<<
    }
    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

It is not working since the update to iOS 6.1 Simulator.

EDIT: i get this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. Have you checked to make sure your `IBOutlet` to your `mapView` is hooked up? If `self.mapView` was `nil`, the app might crash.
2. Have you looked at the `annotation.coordinate` to make sure you're getting a valid result there? Perhaps there is a `MKUserLocation` that doesn't have valid values yet;
3. I know I'm the one who gave you that routine, but I notice that we're not checking for the situation where there were no locations. You probably want something like:

   ```
   if ([self.mapView.annotations count] > 0)
   {
       MKCoordinateRegion region;
       if ([self.mapView.annotations count] > 1)
       {
           region = [self regionForAnnotations:self.mapView.annotations];
           region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(region.center, MKCoordinateSpanMake(region.span.latitudeDelta * 1.05, region.span.longitudeDelta * 1.05));  // expand the region by 5%
       }
       else
       {
           id<MKAnnotation> annotation = self.mapView.annotations[0];
           region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(annotation.coordinate, 100.0, 100.0);
       }
       [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
   }
   ```
4. As an aside, I notice that you're using:

   ```
   parser.attributeNames = @[@"img src="];
   ```

   is that retrieving your image URL? I would have thought that that should just be:

   ```
   parser.attributeNames = @[@"src"];
   ```

   Maybe you've made some change to the parser, but the `attributeDict` of `didStartElement` will never have an object keyed by `img src=`. If the XML tag was `<img src="http://blah.blah.blah/0.jpg">`, the attribute name you're looking for is just `src`.

Comment: 1.) Yes hooked 2.) i don't know how i can test it 3.) I tryed the code and my App will run without errors but with an empty map 4.) corrected :-)

Comment: @CurtisTimoSchmidt 2. Put a NSLog statement right before the line that's giving you the exception. Or better, put a breakpoint in and single step through that code. (See [WWDC 2012 Debug Video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=415) Or see [Xcode users guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_User_Guide/060-Debug_and_Tune_Your_App/debug_app.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH3-SW38).) When you get an exception like this, it`s invariably because some invalid variable is being passed to some method/function.

Comment: The line of code I have marked with a comment, see: `region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(annotation.coordinate, 100.0, 100.0);` if i do `NSLog(@"%@", annotation.coordinate);` befor and after this line I will get a warning: `Format specifies type "id" but the argument has type CCLocationCoordinate2D` I am a bit confused

Comment: @CurtisTimoSchmidt Yeah, so you could do `NSLog(@"%@: %f, %f", annotation, annotation.coordinate.latitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude);`

Comment: Unfortunately, it has brought nothing. There are no details in the log displayed. The app always terminate after `id<MKAnnotation> annotation = self.mapView.annotations[0];`

Comment: @CurtisTimoSchmidt That means it's not getting to that line of code. In your original question you said that you were getting "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT". But I now notice that you updated the question with a different error, "index 0 beyond bounds". Sounds like your map view has no annotations, and thus the attempt to get the first one is failing. See #3 in my answer (where I suggested you check to see if you have some annotations before you try to set the region based upon the annotations), which should address that.

Comment: I'm very sorry ... the server was offline so the error caused.
The file could not be loaded. Everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked you actually have an annotation to use at that point? Maybe your `self.mapView.annotations[0]` returned nil.